# 3D transformation matrix from two vectors

Tags: python, opencv, math, geometry

I have a pair of 3D points in two coordinates systems, and I need to find the transformation matrix (rotation, scale, translation) between the coordinates systems.

For example two points
p0 = (x0,y0,z0)
p1 = (x1,y1,z1)

which correspond to points in another coordinates system:
q0 = (x0', y0', z0')
q1 = (x1', y1', z1')

I need to find the transformation M (R|T) such that
q0 = M * p0
q1 = M * p1

If there is an easy way to do it using opencv or python it would be terrific.

Comment: you'll need at least 3 point coorespondences. One solution is to use "direct linear transform" if I remember it right.

Comment: In general you use homogeneous coordinates so that rotation and translation are embedded in a 4x4 linear transformation matrix. Just solve the resulting linear equation between corresponding points.

Comment: For general affine transformation in 3D you need **4** non-complanar points (4 pairs). Are there any limitations on transformation?

Comment: @MBo 3D Camera movement is a rigid transform with 3dof for rotation and 3dof for translation. Thinking about it, 2 point pairs (3d) -> 6 linear equations should be enough?

Comment: @Micka Consider 3 pairs (0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0)=>(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0). One possible affine tranform is rotation about Y axis by Pi/2. It maps point (0,0,1) to (-1,0,0). Another possible affine tranform - the same rotation, then scaling along X axis by -1 (or any factor). It maps the same point (0,0,1) to (+1,0,0).

Comment: @MBo scaling isnt allowed in rigid transforms. Only rotation and translation. In general (full affine) you are right because there are more dof.

Comment: @Micka But author says about `(rotation, scale, translation)` in the beginning and mentions (R|T) later. That is why I am not sure about rigid transforms. Anyway, his 2 pairs are not enough :)

Answer (score 3):

We can interpret your problem in this way. You want to find a matrix M such that

```
    for matrix P = [p1 p2] and Q = [q1 q2], Q = MP.
```

We can then solve for M:

```
    M = Q.dot(numpy.linalg.pinv(P))
```